# Limiting register usage in CUDA: __launch_bounds__ vs maxrregcount

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nvcc

From the [NVIDIA CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ixzz4kk6SRKqY):

> Register usage can be controlled using the `maxrregcount` compiler
>   option or launch bounds as described in Launch Bounds.

From my understanding (and correct me if I'm wrong), while `-maxrregcount` limits the number of registers the entire `.cu` file may use, the `__launch_bounds__` qualifier defines the `maxThreadsPerBlock` and `minBlocksPerMultiprocessor` for each `__global__` kernel. These two accomplish the same task, but in two different ways.

My usage requires me to have `40` registers per thread to maximize the performance. Thus, I can use `-maxrregcount 40`. I can also force `40` registers by using `__launch_bounds__(256, 6)` but this causes load & store register spills.

What is the difference between the two to cause these register spills?

Comment: Maybe it is an easy answer: You probably require 40 registers per thread and not per block. - If you just miswrote it in your answer:Please provide information about your GPU. Maybe you just did a simple mistake in your calculations. And what are the block dimensions in both cases you launched your kernel with? (I assume the number of blocks is high enough)

Comment: @Shadow You're correct about 40 regs per thread - my mistake/typo. About the GPU, it's running on a GPU with Maxwell architecture using CC 5.3. <<<grid, block>>> sizes are (132,0,0) and (16,16,0) respectively and can run 2048 threads simultaneously (Tegra TX1). The kernel executes correctly in both cases, but there is spillage when using __launch_bounds__ but not with -maxrregcount even though the register per thread usage is the same in both cases.

Comment: Did you compare the runtime of both versions?

Comment: When comparing the actual times of the kernel compiled both ways, it's a matter of 10-20 _us_, but it averages 7-9 _ms_ in both scenarios, so the time difference is very minimal in the grand scheme of things for my application. This question was asked more out of curiosity. The only reason I notice the time is because it can reach time under 7 ms using `-maxrregcount` while `__launch_bounds__` results in consistent 7 ms+ kernel times.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The preface of this question is that, quoting the `CUDA C Programming Guide`,

> the fewer registers a kernel uses, the more threads and thread blocks
>   are likely to reside on a multiprocessor, which can improve
>   performance.

Now, `__launch_bounds__` and `maxregcount` limit register usage by two different mechanisms.

**`__launch_bounds__`**

`nvcc` decides the number of registers to be used by a `__global__` function through balancing the performance and the generality of the kernel launch setup. Saying it differently, such a choice of the number of used registers "guarantees effectiveness" for different numbers of threads per block and of blocks per multiprocessor. However, if an approximate idea of the maximum number of threads per block and (possibly) of the minimum number of blocks per multiprocessor is available at compile-time, then this information can be used to optimize the kernel for such launches. In other words

```
#define MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK 256
#define MIN_BLOCKS_PER_MP     2

__global__ void
__launch_bounds__(MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK, MIN_BLOCKS_PER_MP)
fooKernel(int *inArr, int *outArr)
{
    // ... Computation of kernel
}
```

informs the compiler of a likely launch configuration, so that `nvcc` can select the number of registers for such a launch configuration in an "optimal" way.

The `MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK` parameter is mandatory, while the `MIN_BLOCKS_PER_MP` parameter is optional. Also note that if the kernel is launched with a number of threads per block larger than `MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK`, the kernel launch will fail.

The limiting mechanism is described in the `Programming Guide` as follows:

> If launch bounds are specified, the compiler first derives from them
>   the upper limit `L` on the number of registers the kernel should use
>   to ensure that `minBlocksPerMultiprocessor` blocks (or a single block
>   if `minBlocksPerMultiprocessor` is not specified) of
>   `maxThreadsPerBlock` threads can reside on the multiprocessor. The
>   compiler then optimizes register usage in the following way:
>
> - If the initial register usage is higher than `L`, the compiler reduces it further until it becomes less or equal to `L`, usually at
>     the expense of more local memory usage and/or higher number of
>     instructions;

Accordingly, `__launch_bounds__` can lead to register spill.

**`maxrregcount`**

`maxrregcount` is a compiler flag that simply hardlimits the number of employed registers to a number set by the user, at variance with `__launch_bounds__`, by forcing the compiler to rearrange its use of registers. When the compiler can't stay below the imposed limit, it will simply spill it to local memory which is in fact `DRAM`. Even this local variables are stored in global `DRAM` memory  variables can be cached in L1, L2.

Comment: @Shadow: I think you are wrong. An SMM has 4 warp schedulers, each of which can pick warps from different blocks. Also, the register file gets swapped in or out as necessary with (no? very little?) overhead. So while the number of blocks associated with an SMM at any one time is limited, it's not register spilling that's limiting it.

Comment: @Shadow: No. A block is bound to an SM (although it's conceivable that it could be moved); and a warp schedular is a physical mechanism on an SM. Also, we were talking about the register file, not memory.

Comment: @JackOLantern: To make sure I understand this correctly, `__launch_bounds__` optimizes the kernel based on the `minBlocksPerMultiprocessor` and `maxThreadsPerBlock`, and thus will guess at the best # of registers per thread based on those parameters. On the other hand, `-maxrregcount` will force a register limit upon the code, and thus will optimize based on the limit (not the block sizes like `__launch_bounds__` and will result in different optimizations when compared).

Comment: @Kelsius Yes, you are right. `__launch_bounds__` fixes a limit `L` so to make the launch possible with the indicated `minBlocksPerMultiprocessor` and `maxThreadsPerBlock`. Then, it optimizes the number of registers, while satisfying this limit. In `-maxrregcount`, differently to `__launch_bounds__`, the limit is set by the user, and optimization follows the set limit.